# Reference error: bodyData is not defined at eval

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

there are 2 block of ejs code on my html page that I'm trying to display data from nodejs, 1 is for dropdown menu, another one is for displaying table. the dropdown was fine, but for some reason, table is not working.

```
node.js

 case "ucgw2":
        axios.get(apiurl+"/api/cdr-ucgw2",{
        data: {starttime:starttime, endtime:endtime, setlimit:setlimit, customer:customer}
      })
        .then(function (body) {

          // handle success

          console.log("channel data = ",body.data)
          res.render('html-cdr',{bodyData:body.data, startday:startday, startmonth:startmonth, startyear:startyear, starthour:starthour, startmin:startmin, endday:endday, endmonth:endmonth, endyear:endyear,endhour:endhour, endmin:endmin, customer:customer});
        })
        .catch(function (error) {

          // handle error
          
          req.flash('error', error);
          res.render('html-cdr',{bodyData:body.data, startday:startday, startmonth:startmonth, startyear:startyear, starthour:starthour, startmin:startmin, endday:endday, endmonth:endmonth, endyear:endyear,endhour:endhour, endmin:endmin, customer:customer});
        })


html table (ejs)
         <%
                    if(bodyData !== "" && bodyData !== null){
                    var i=1;
                    bodyData.forEach(function(body){ 
                %>  
                <tr>
                    <td><%=body.company_name %></td>
                </tr>
                <%  i++; }) %>
                <% } else{ %>
                <% } %>
```

i tried changing to another variable but it still not working, error says body data undefined, i made sure that i double checked everything without leaving out stuff

Comment: Can you post the result of `console.log(body)` from the `then` callback?

Comment: `channel data =  [
  {
    calldate: '2022-12-07T00:00:03Z',
    src: '+60378000148',
    company_name: 'Dot Dash Technologies',
    dst: 'tdial',
    channel: 'SIP/tm-multisip-0000130f',
    lastapp: 'Dial',
    duration: '0',
    disposition: 'FAILED',
    uniqueid: '1670342403.7584',
    did: '+60378000148',
    did_clean: '0378000148',
    customer_rate_plan: '123456'
  }`

Comment: then this error came out 

`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:530:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\test001\Downloads\billing-web\nodejs-workspace\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\test001\Downloads\billing-web\nodejs-workspace\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:280:5)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\test001\Downloads\billing-web\nodejs-workspace\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render`